# How do we install pear packages at our ISP

Tags: pear

here's a total rookie question about pear packages:

We want to install a php application (open source) onto a hosted site. The app relies on pear packages. These can be downloaded from the app's website.
Our ISP supports pear.

But how do we install the packages???

We can do PHP but are new to pear. We searched and could not find any appropriate answers.
We phoned our ISP and they can't tell us so probably we are asking the wrong questions.

We only have access to the website via ftp (we use Filezilla). There is no command line available to access the remote website.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know that "Our ISP supports pear."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install PEAR packages locally and then upload them through SFTP onto your server. See the "shared host instalattion instructions" on the pear manual: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php

Answer (score 1):

Read the section about using PEAR_RemoteInstaller in the [Installation of a local PEAR copy on a shared host](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php) documentation. There is also a section there describing how to do this "the traditional way".